# Remove orphaned App registrations, that have no resources

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

If I create an Azure Kubernetes Service, it will create an app registration. When I delete the cluster, the app registration is left behind.

I was following the workshop here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/aks-workshop/02-deploy-aks and afterwards, I deleted the resource group to clean up all the resources. However, the service principals (or app registrations, not sure what the difference is) are all left behind, even though they are now orphaned, no longer associated to any existing resources. I can see the details for this SP by running `az ad sp show --id http://$AKS_CLUSTER_NAME`

Is there a way to clear out these orphaned app registrations without looking through them and manually picking out the ones that don't have resources? Preferably using the `az` CLI.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is any way exists even with CLI unless you manually delete the app. However you can use the **`az ad app delete`** with your own script to navigate through the apps and delete them

Comment: az ad sp delete --id $(az ad sp list --display-name "$REG-pull" --query "[].appId" -o tsv)